# Beginner's Tensorflow question: Can't get the dimensions for a simple linear equation right

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, dimensions

I'm starting to dabble in Tensorflow and want to teach a model a simple linear equation. So to generate training data, I'm writing a little script to produce two arrays, one of 100 tuples of two random integers (x1, x2) and one where each value is y = 2*x1 + 5*x2:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

list_len = 100

x_data_list = []
y_data_list = []

for i in range(list_len):
    x1 = np.random.randint(100)
    x2 = np.random.randint(100)
    x_data_list.append((x1, x2))
    y_data_list.append(2 * x1 + 5 * x2)

x_data = np.asarray(x_data_list)
y_data = np.asarray(y_data_list)
```

Then I want to build a simple model to learn the relationship between these two arrays:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, name="Input_layer", input_shape=(2,), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, name="Hidden_layer", activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, name="Output_layer", activation="relu")
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=100)
```

The code runs, but it's quite useless - it starts with a ridiculously high loss, and that loss never goes down over those 100 epochs.

After some attempts at troubleshooting, my theory is that the problem lies with the dimensionality of the `input_shape` parameter in the input layer which I got wrong in such a way that the model doesn't know it's supposed to map two input integers from x_data to one output integer from y_data. But my attempts to change that parameter only get me an error that the model expects another dimensionality of input data. And (2,) is what I get when I pass one of the instances of x_data into `np.shape()`.

Anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, hpaulj, that is indeed smoother.

Just to wrap this up: I've worked longer on my own code, and got it to work in the meantime. The problem was, I think, that when I generated my data as a list and then converted it into an np.array, the conversion seemed to have output an array of lists rather than something that was an array all the way through in all dimensions. I've meanwhile changed it into a data generation that starts with an np.array to begin with, and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this addresses the `fit` problem, but generating the data can be streamlined:

```
In [69]: x_data.shape
Out[69]: (100, 2)
In [70]: y_data.shape
Out[70]: (100,)
In [71]: x1=np.random.randint(100,size=(100,2))
In [72]: x1.shape
Out[72]: (100, 2)
In [73]: y1 = np.dot(x1,[2,5])
In [74]: y1.shape
Out[74]: (100,)
```

I don't have `tensorflow`, so won't try your model.  But with `numpy's` own leastsqr fit:

```
In [78]: np.linalg.lstsq(x1,y1,rcond=-1)
Out[78]: 
(array([2., 5.]),
 array([7.96628473e-25]),
 2,
 array([783.14344837, 278.42295034]))
In [79]: np.linalg.lstsq(x_data,y_data,rcond=-1)
Out[79]: 
(array([2., 5.]),
 array([2.41433345e-25]),
 2,
 array([743.02650756, 296.1715872 ]))
```

I'm not sure what the `rcond=-1` does, but without it I got a warning.